# Unserialize objects from in-memory ASCII instead of from a file connection

Tags: json, r, serialization, ascii

### Actual question

How can I serialize objects to ASCII and unserialize them again from ASCII **without** having to write to and read from a file connection (i.e. from ASCII that is in-memory)?

### Background

In a state-less client-server framework, I would like to make certain information persistent accross calls (**serialize >> send to client >> get serialized info back from client >> unserialize**) without caching it on the server side.

Note that my JSON object/strong also contains *other unserialized* information and is thus mixed with the serialized information which is why the approach explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258511/r-serialize-objects-to-text-file-and-back-again) doesn't completely do the trick.

Now, the thing is that I would like to *unserialize* the object solely based on the already-read JSON string. So to speak: from "in-memory ASCII" instead of from a file connection. How would I do that?

Here's what I tried:

```
require(forecast)
```

### Approach 1

```
## SERVER: estimates initial model and writes JSON to socket
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers, trace = TRUE)

## Model trace:
# ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,1,1)[12]                    : Inf
# ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 967.6773
# ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,1,0)[12]                    : 965.4487
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12]                    : 957.1797
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,1,1)[12]                    : 963.5291
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 956.7848
# ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 959.4575
# ARIMA(0,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 958.8701
# ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 961.3943
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 956.7848
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,1,0)[12]                    : 964.7139
# 
# Best model: ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]  

fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(model))
deparsed <- deparse(model)

json_out <- list(data = AirPassengers, model = deparsed, fc = fc)
json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_out)

## CLIENT: keeps estimated model, updates data, writes to socket
json_in <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)
json_in$data <- window(AirPassengers, end = 1949 + (1/12 * 14))

## SERVER: reads new JSON and applies model to new data
data <- json_in$data
model_0 <- json_in$model
model_1 <- eval(parse(text = model_0))

## Model trace:
# ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,1,1)[12]                    : Inf
# ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 967.6773
# ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,1,0)[12]                    : 965.4487
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12]                    : 957.1797
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,1,1)[12]                    : 963.5291
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 956.7848
# ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 959.4575
# ARIMA(0,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 958.8701
# ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 961.3943
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    : 956.7848
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,1,0)[12]                    : 964.7139
# 
# Best model: ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]  

# Warning message:
#   In auto.arima(x = structure(list(x = structure(c(112, 118, 132,  :
#       Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated

fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(Arima(data, model = model_1)))

## And so on ...
```

That works, but note that `eval(parse(text = json_in$model))` actually **re-runs** the call to `auto.arima()` instead of just re-establishing/unserializing the object (note the trace information printed to the console that I included as comments).

That's not completely what I want as simply want to re-establish the final model object in the fastest possible way.

That's why I turned to`serialize()` next.

### Approach 2

```
## SERVER: estimates initial model and writes JSON to socket
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers, trace = TRUE)
fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(model))
serialized <- serialize(model, NULL)
class(serialized)

json_out <- list(data = AirPassengers, model = serialized, fc = fc)
json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_out)

## CLIENT: keeps estimated model, updates data, writes to socket
json_in <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)
json_in$data <- window(AirPassengers, end = 1949 + (1/12 * 14))

## SERVER: reads new JSON and applies model to new data
data <- json_in$data
model_0 <- json_in$model
try(model_1 <- unserialize(model_0))
## --> error:
# Error in unserialize(model_0) : 
#   character vectors are no longer accepted by unserialize()
```

Unfortunately, function `unserialize()` expects a file connection instead of "plain ASCII".

So that's why I need to do the following workaround.

### Approach 3

```
## SERVER: estimates initial model and writes JSON to socket
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers, trace = TRUE)
fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(model))
con <- file("serialized", "w+")
serialize(model, con)
close(con)

json_out <- list(data = AirPassengers, model = "serialized", fc = fc)
json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_out)

## CLIENT: keeps estimated model, updates data, writes to socket
json_in <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)
json_in$data <- window(AirPassengers, end = 1949 + (1/12 * 14))

## SERVER: reads new JSON and applies model to new data
data <- json_in$data
model_0 <- json_in$model
con <- file(model_0, "r+")
model_1 <- unserialize(con)
close(con)
fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(Arima(data, model = model_1)))

## And so on ...
```

Unserializing works now without the actual `auto.arima()` call being re-evaluated. But it's against my state-less paradigm as now the actual information is cached on the server side instead of actually being sent via the JSON object/string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this fit your needs?

It follows the general strategy in your **Approach 2**. The only difference is that it uses `as.character()` to convert the serialized object to a character vector before passing it to `toJSON()`, and then uses `as.raw(as.hexmode())` to convert it back to a raw vector "on the other side". (I've marked the two edited lines with comments reading `## <<- Edited`.)

```
library(forecast)

## SERVER: estimates initial model and writes JSON to socket
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers, trace = TRUE)
fc <- as.data.frame(forecast(model))
serialized <- as.character(serialize(model, NULL)) ## <<- Edited
class(serialized)


json_out <- list(data = AirPassengers, model = serialized, fc = fc)
json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_out)

## CLIENT: keeps estimated model, updates data, writes to socket
json_in <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)
json_in$data <- window(AirPassengers, end = 1949 + (1/12 * 14))

## SERVER: reads new JSON and applies model to new data
data <- json_in$data
model_0 <- as.raw(as.hexmode(json_in$model))       ## <<- Edited

unserialize(model_0)
## Series: AirPassengers 
## ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12]                    
## 
## Coefficients:
##           ma1
##       -0.3184
## s.e.   0.0877
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 137.3:  log likelihood=-508.32
## AIC=1020.64   AICc=1020.73   BIC=1026.39
```

Comment: Yes! You totally made my day! I'm not really familiar with the `raw` data type and thus would have never guessed that I need to use the combination of `as.hexmode()` and `as.raw()` without your help. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Rappster -- Cool. Glad that helped! I got that idiom a while ago from [this old SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5950338/980833) of Joris Meys', and it actually helped me understand quite a bit better what that raw data type is all about. Not directly related, but to "see" a bit more what's going on, you can play around a bit with statments like these: `charToRaw("ab"); serialize("ab", NULL); charToRaw("AB"); serialize("AB", NULL); serialize(list("AB"), NULL)` (and then of course figure out the code needed to invert the transformations). Cheers.

Comment: Alternatively, in that next to last line, one can do `as.raw(strtoi(json_in$model, base=16))`. That's what `as.hexmode()`  uses under the hood. In both cases, the essential task is to go from a two letter character string that denotes a particular byte using hexadecimal representation **to** the integer that represents that same value in base 10 and then finally **to** the 8-bit byte that represents the same number in binary.

Comment: One more note: IMHO, R's print method for vectors of class `"raw"` obscures the transformation that takes place in on the way from character string to byte. If it (infelicitously!) printed bytes as a sequence of ones and zeros, rather than using the same two-letter hexadecimal code as were used by the input `"character"` vectors, the transformation would be obvious!